# ORM with joins, logic and performance interrogations (using JPA and Spring)

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa, orm

I have three tables : groups, users, and group_members. The groups table is bond to a Group class, users with the User class and group_members is used to model the many-to-many relationship between them.

Here's what the group_members looks like

```
id | user_id | group_id
---+---------+---------
```

Now let's say I want to add a member to a group knowing the group id and the user id. I have two methods: either I get the group using its id, I update his member list and save the group or I create a SQL request that directly updates group_members. Here, the second method seems less time consuming, but I have to write a specific SQL request, while with the first one I can let JPA make the job.

Here's my question: is it more relevant to use the first or the second method and why? Isn't there a method so that I can let JPA do the work, without performing more requests than the second solution?

Thanks.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why we usually map our join tables to actual entities instead of getting the jpa to map the `ManyToMany` to your join table. It allows you to just create a `GroupMember` entity by itself, given the Ids of your user and group and using the EntityManager's `persist()` method. If you're not sure what I mean I can illustrate it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with the 'first method' is if a group has 10000 members then you might be (inadvertently) pulling everyone just to add an additional member.

But assuming on average a member do not belong to more than 4-5 groups then the reverse sound more efficient (get the member and add additional group to its list).

Of course with the 'second method' you can create the association with one single insert, but defeats the whole purpose of using ORM in the first place?

Comment: I agree with you, but isn't it stupid to keep the ORM logic if it greatly alter the performances? Isn't there a way to take advantage both of the ORM and the perfs?

Comment: Ofcourse there is, on my repository classes I often autowire both EntityManager and JdbcOperations. Have to be careful with transaction management though.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the number of users is large and the number of groups relatively small, then you can achieve relatively good efficiency by inverting your logic and adding the group to the user:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();
    ...
```

The groups set defaults to being lazily loaded. In practice this means that it will be loaded with a select statement as soon as you attempt to read or write to it.

Note that the corresponding Group entity does *not* have a matching relationship modelled with a 'Set<User> members'. You don't want to load a Group along with it's 10,000 users in order to add one more user.

If that's not good enough you could model the join table as an entity, but that's probably more trouble than it's worth in this instance.

Here's some sample queries issued by Hibernate in the scenario that I described:

```
    TypedQuery<Group> gq = em.createQuery("select g from Group g where g.name='two'", Group.class);
    Group g = gq.getSingleResult();
    TypedQuery<User> uq = em.createQuery("select u from User u where u.username='u1' ", User.class);
    User u = uq.getSingleResult();

Hibernate: select group0_.id as id1_0_, group0_.name as name2_0_ from groups group0_ where group0_.name='two'
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.username as username2_1_ from users user0_ where user0_.username='u1'

    u.getGroups().add(g);

Hibernate: select groups0_.users_id as users_id1_1_0_, groups0_.groups_id as groups_i2_2_0_, group1_.id as id1_0_1_, group1_.name as name2_0_1_ from users_groups groups0_ inner join groups group1_ on groups0_.groups_id=group1_.id where groups0_.users_id=?
Hibernate: insert into users_groups (users_id, groups_id) values (?, ?)
```

I think that this is a perfectly reasonable strategy for this particular use case as you will not have many of your users performing these operations simultaneously and the single extra query is not going to result in any performance problems.

Comment: You're right, but that is assuming you don't bind a Set<User> to the Group entity. Let's say you want to easily get the members of a group: you just moved the problem because you then will be forced to create a SQL query manually. I think that is a missing functionnality in Hibernate that could be handled quite simply

Comment: Well, it really depends on the user count, etc. But it is a very simple query: TypedQuery<User> uq = em.createQuery("select u from User u where :g member of u.groups ", User.class);

Comment: I'll also add that you were discussing whether or not it's a good idea to write SQL to maintain the join table. If you do that then your different updating paradigms are likely to bite you sometime down the track. Sticking to straight JPA in this instance helps minimise that risk.